# REST Call (post method) using soap ui

Tags: json, rest, soapui

Below is request body.
I would like to add a user through REST call (post method) using SOAP UI.
Please explain.

```
{
  "activated": true,
  "email": "string",
  "firstName": "string",
  "langKey": "string",
  "lastModifiedBy": "string",
  "login": "string",
  "password": "string",
  "userGroups": [
    {
      "groupName": "string",
      "id": 0,
       "roles": [
        {
          "id": "string",
           "name": "string",
          "privileges": [
            {
              "id": "string",
              "name": "string"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: Do you swagger definition or wadl ? have you imported there?

Comment: Its a swagger definition.

Comment: Then what is the exact issue that you are facing to do so?